# How to monitor with logging to show voip service disconnections

Tags: linux, udp, connection, voip

We rent a few servers in different data centers around the world. Our Atlanta location is the pits. We disconnect at least 10 times a day. We thought it was the cables, so we replaced them to the point where I have a new machine now. The replaced the old machine and gave me a brand new machine.

Since last night,  2300 hours, we have disconnected 9 times. Sometimes I have to relog into ssh and other times I do not.

We disconnect for 15 - 50 seconds before we auto log back into the server.

What program can I install to monitor a direct connection from voip client to voip server to show the data center this is happening?

Comment: Does it need to be open source?

Comment: Not at all. I have devoted so much of my time over the last 2 months that any solution would be welcomed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.